# Can you use two iOS apps with the same Firestore database?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project that requires a user iOS app and a creator iOS app, such as how Uber has a driver iOS app and a customer iOS app.

Can I use the same Firebase project and Firestore database for both?

How would I set this up with the GoogleService-Info.plist? as both apps will have a different Bundle Identifier.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your project console, go to settings and scroll down. you should see the button to download the GoogleService-Info.plist of the iOS app you already have. If you click on the "Add app" button you can add another iOS app for the same project, which will have its won .plist file.

[image]